# How to read yaml files in laravel?

Tags: laravel, yaml

In the project I'm working on, it's a CMS, and within it I manage brand website themes. My question is I need to read the header of the file, how do I do this inside the controller?

I need somehow to read this file and list the titles of headers or footers that exist in it.

- header:
- header_submenu_menu
- header_submenu_models
- footer_mobile:
- footer_desktop:
- footer_socialmedia:

I'm using this package: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/yaml

[image: menu.yaml]

Comment: Is the package you mentioned in your question not working?? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a great article about YAML [here](https://medium.com/smallprogtips/parsing-yaml-files-in-laravel-5-bca2ead5242e).

To excerpt from the page, you only need to follow a few simple steps:

1 Install the Symfony YAML Component using composer:

```
composer require symfony/yaml
```

2 In `config/app.php` under `aliases`, add the following entry:

```
'Yaml' => 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml'
```

3 In your desired controller/service:

```
use Yaml;
$yamlContents = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('filepath'));
```

And that's it.

This solution works fairly universally, relying on PHP's composer library for you to include the library, then simply calling parse methods to unmarshal your YAML into a usable PHP variable. For the example shown here, try something like:

```
print_r($yamlContents)
```

To see how to use the data now that it's been converted.

Comment: I've seen that one.

Comment: Then what's the specific issue you're having? That article is exactly what any of us could explain. Install the package you want to use with composer, and then use it via an Alias.

Comment: In case I need to list the titles, this file, being that I do not have much experience with laravel with yaml, I'm kind of lost. This data will be listed in a view.

Comment: Once you've parsed the YAML into a PHP variable, you can iterate the data the same way you would normally (ie, contents[0].title) - I'm still not sure what you're asking

Comment: you will be downvoted for posting an answer with only a link to an external resource... WHile this can solve the problem in the answer it's better to include the main part of the linked resource here, because in the future this resource can go offline and become unuseful... so please improve your answer

Comment: How would I do that? This interaction.

Comment: @DaFois I was unaware this was the convention. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RomuloSousa I've added a way for you to introspect the value using `print_r` to my answer, but ultimately you need to provide this data to the view the same way you provide all data. I don't know how else to answer the question you've asked, so please either accept this answer, or rephrase / ask a new question with more specific details of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I did it this way.


`$value = Yaml::parse('storage\app\themes\default\resources\views\config\menu.yaml');

        print_r($value);`

Comment: I'm glad this was able to help you get what you needed @RomuloSousa. Could you please mark my answer as "✔ Accepted" if this got you what you needed?

Comment: But it did not work, I have the following error.

file_get_contents (storage / app / themes / default / resources / views / config / menu.yaml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Unfortunately it's frowned upon to continue long conversations in comments, and you're not of a high enough reputation to chat, but you should've let me know that was the issue you were running into. As a heads up, I don't believe the solution you have is doing what you think it is, but you are able to use the YAML parser as you asked, so I'm glad you've got that far. Double check that `$value` actually has what you want, and good luck on finishing your project! If you have any more questions, please feel free to open a new question.

Comment: @RomuloSousa Change persmission (recursively) on storage directory - allow files to be read/executed. If you are familiar with concept try these commands `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache` (and if your web-server user is named `www-data`).

Comment: Ok,I'm using wampserver

Comment: I suggest opening another question about this, as comments are not the place for us to discuss separate problems. However, you're probably just referencing the wrong path relatively to where you're executing `Yaml::parse` - Try doing stuff like `Yaml::parse(__DIR__ . "/../../storage/app/blah/menu.yaml") to open it specifically relative to the file you're in, and be sure the output of that path makes sense for your file system.